# How to start Python virtual environment in .bat batch file?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, python-venv

I need to set up a long list of temporary environment variables every time when I start a Python Flask app on Windows 10. Now I would like to create a batch file to run with all settings in one double click. The following lines run well if I copy them and paste to cmd prompt, but I couldn't run them in the batch file.

The execution of batch file always gets tripped and exited at the 2nd line `venv\scripts\activate` in the batch file, which has no issue at all if I copy and paste line by line at cmd.

```
cd C:\py\project
venv\scripts\activate

set env1=val1
set env2=val2
set FLASK_APP=some.py

flask run
```

Comment: In addition to the answer already provided, you should use `CD /D "C:\py\project"`, `Set "env1=val1"`, `Set "env2=val2"`, and `Set "FLASK_APP=some.py"` too.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

One of the many (far too many) quirks of .bat files is that if you launch another .bat file, it doesn't know where to return to.
You need to explicitly `call` it:

```
call venv\scripts\activate
```

Answer (score 1):

you can just use

```
start venv\Scripts\activate
```

This will open up a new terminal just like that... you can pass other commands using the **&&** or **&** sign.