# python virtualenv doesnt persist through another process in window

Tags: python, python-3.x, batch-file, window, virtualenv

Say I have a virtual python env calls `example_venv` and I have an executable calls `application` that I need to launch within that specific python environment, how can this be done?

In linux, Ihave this `lanch.sh` script:

```
#!/bin/bash
. example_venv/script/activate
./application
```

^ That works like a charm. Any python processes from within my application will be able to loads libraries from `example_venv`.

In window, here is what I have in a `lanch.bat` file:

```
example_venv/Script/activate.bat & application.exe %*
```

This launches the application, however if I run any python processes inside application, that python processes doesn't seems to know anything about the `example_venv`.

Comment: You should have two lines in your batch file. 1) `CALL example_venv/Script/activate.bat`. 2) `application.exe %*`

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

[How to start Python virtual environment in .bat batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56026422/how-to-start-python-virtual-environment-in-bat-batch-file)

Quoting the answer,

> One of the many (far too many) quirks of .bat files is that if you launch another .bat file, it doesn't know where to return to.
> You need to explicitly call it:

```
call venv\scripts\activate
```

I believe that should resolve your issue.

On a side note, you can also reference the python executable in the venv directly instead of having to activate the environment:

```
%~dp0venv\scripts\python.exe [arguments] **
```

** Assuming the batch file sits in the same directory as the venv directory. *%~dp0* refers to the current directory of the running batch file.